# Fitting background in Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, backgrounds

I need that the grey background also includes the labels T1 and T2

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,decorations.pathmorphing,backgrounds,positioning,fit,petri}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [rectangle,draw] (set a) [label=right:$T_1$]                 {\textit{SET A}};
\node [rectangle,draw] (set b) [below=of set a, label=right:$T_2$] {\textit{SET B}};

\draw [->] (set a) to node [auto] {\textit{q}} (set b);

\begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
\node [fill=black!30,fit=(set a) (set b)] {};
\end{pgfonlayer}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Jake's answer is correct but  you have a problem if you want a lightgray wrapper and a different background.

Then  if you add something to the picture; you need to use nested tikzpictures (I'm not afraid of this) . Sometimes you need to use nested pictures with caution.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node at (5,0){extra};
\node {\begin{tikzpicture}[
      show background rectangle, 
      background rectangle/.style={fill=lightgray},
      box/.style={draw, font=\itshape}
  ]
  \node [box] (set a) [label=right:$T_1$]                 {SET A};
  \node [box] (set b) [below=of set a, label=right:$T_2$] {SET B};

  \draw [-latex] (set a) to node [auto] {\textit{q}} (set b);
\end{tikzpicture}}; 
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Gonzalo's answer s fine also but  if you add an extra node, you need to program the picture with order in this case, I think it's better to use a scope and `local bounding box` like this :

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,backgrounds,positioning,fit}
\begin{document} 

\begin{tikzpicture}[typea/.style={draw,rectangle,font=\itshape}]
  \node at (5,0){extra}; 
  \begin{scope}[local bounding box=bb]
     \node [typea] (set a) [label=right:$T_1$] {SET A};
     \node [typea] (set b) [below=of set a, label=right:$T_2$] {SET B};
     \draw [->] (set a) to node [auto,font=\itshape] {q} (set b); 
  \end{scope}

   \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
     \node [fill=black!30,fit=(bb)] {};
  % Jake's remark is fine, (bb) avoids (bb.north west) (bb.south east)
   \end{pgfonlayer}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Before the option `label` ( for old users of TikZ) we used simple nodes and in this case you can avoid dummy nodes

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[
      box/.style={draw, font=\itshape}
  ]
  \node [box] (set a)  {SET A};
  \node [box] (set b) [below=of set a] {SET B};
  \node[anchor=west,right=6pt] (T1) at (set a.east){$T_1$};
  \node[anchor=west,right=6pt] (T2) at (set b.east){$T_2$};  
  \draw [-latex] (set a) to node [auto] {\textit{q}} (set b); 

\begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
   \node [fill=black!30,fit=(set a) (T2)] {};
\end{pgfonlayer}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Finally you can use `label` without dummy nodes with the option `name`, I use pgf 2.1 CVS and perhaps this option is a new one (I don't know)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,backgrounds,positioning,fit}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [rectangle,draw] (set a) [label={[name=T1]right:$T_1$}]                 {\textit{SET A}};
\node [rectangle,draw] (set b) [below=of set a, label={[name=T2]right:$T_2$}] {\textit{SET B}};

\begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
   \node [fill=black!30,fit=(set a) (T2)] {};
\end{pgfonlayer}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: "Who's afraid of the Big Bad Nested-TikZ-Pictures?"  (Doesn't quite scan as well as the original)

Comment: More seriously, your last solution (naming the labels) is the one that I would have posted if you hadn't.  It seems the most natural and robust solution.

Comment: Yes "Who's afraid of the Big Bad Nested-TikZ-Pictures?" !! In the sources of pgf, I found this :  `\def\tikzpicture{\def\tikzpicture{\begingroup\def\endtikzpicture{\tikzexternal@origendpicture\endgroup} etc. `  with this comment  `make sure that nested \tikzpicture are processed normally` (tikzlibraryexternal.code.tex  by Christian Feuersaenger)

Comment: @AndrewStacey Yes naming the labels is fine but finally perhaps the old method ( adding nodes) is more  readable. In this case, the user know that labels are `label node`. In the pgfmanual the example gives : `\node [circle,draw,label={[name=label node]above left:$a,b$}] {};`. I don't like very much long lines of code but "everyone does what they want" !

Comment: I missed the use of `local bounding box` first time I read this.  I didn't know of that - yet again, I learn something new from your answers.

Answer (score 9):

You can just provide the option `show background rectangle, background rectangle/.style={fill=lightgray}` to the `tikzpicture`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,backgrounds,positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    show background rectangle, 
    background rectangle/.style={fill=lightgray},
    box/.style={draw, font=\itshape}
]
\node [box] (set a) [label=right:$T_1$]                 {SET A};
\node [box] (set b) [below=of set a, label=right:$T_2$] {SET B};

\draw [-latex] (set a) to node [auto] {\textit{q}} (set b);


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

You can switch off the padding of the background rectangle by using the option `tight background`.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the `current bounding box`:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,decorations.pathmorphing,backgrounds,positioning,fit,petri}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[typea/.style={draw,rectangle,font=\itshape}]
\node [typea] (set a) [label=right:$T_1$] {SET A};
\node [typea] (set b) [below=of set a, label=right:$T_2$] {SET B};

\draw [->] (set a) to node [auto,font=\itshape] {q} (set b);

\begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
\node [fill=black!30,fit=(current bounding box.north west) (current bounding box.south east)] {};
\end{pgfonlayer}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If you want the `fit` command to include all anchors of a certain node (as is the case here), you can just provide the node name: `fit=(current bounding box)` will give you the same result as `fit=(current bounding box.north west) (current bounding box.south east)`.

Answer (score 5):

There must be certainly a better way than this. This method is quite ugly and too manual, but it works.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,decorations.pathmorphing,backgrounds,positioning,fit,petri}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [rectangle,draw] (set a) [label=right:$T_1$]                 {\textit{SET A}};
\node [rectangle,draw] (set b) [below=of set a, label=right:$T_2$] {\textit{SET B}};
%\node  (set c) [right=of set a,xshift=-0.85cm] {}; % A dummy node not necessary
\node (set d) [right=of set b,xshift=-0.85cm] {}; % Another dummy node

\draw [->] (set a) to node [auto] {\textit{q}} (set b);

\begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
\node [fill=black!30,fit=(set a)(set d)] {}; % enough to add two diagonal nodes
\end{pgfonlayer}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you are having many sets like `A`, one below the other, it is enough to define one dummy node to the right of last node like in

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,decorations.pathmorphing,backgrounds,positioning,fit,petri}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [rectangle,draw] (set a) [label=right:$T_1$]                 {\textit{SET A}};
\node [rectangle,draw] (set b) [below=of set a, label=right:$T_2$] {\textit{SET B}};
\node [rectangle,draw] (set c) [below=of set b,label=right:$T_3$]                 {\textit{SET C}};
\node [rectangle,draw] (set d) [below=of set c, label=right:$T_4$] {\textit{SET D}};
%\node  (set e) [right=of set a,xshift=-0.85cm] {}; % A dummy node not really needed
\node (set f) [right=of set d,xshift=-0.85cm,yshift=-0.15cm] {}; % Another dummy node, add yshift also as needed.

\draw [->] (set a) to node [auto] {\textit{q}} (set b);

\begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
\node [fill=black!30,fit=(set a) (set f)] {}; 
\end{pgfonlayer}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]